# MySQL: return max of the last 5 digits from column

Tags: mysql, regex

just need help with regular expression in mysql query please:

```
column ISRC
GBCQV0700378
GBCQV0700382
GBCQV0700387
```

i need 00387 returned to me (the biggest number)
i'm using:

```
SELECT max(ISRC) REGEXP "/(\d{5})$/" FROM digital_info; // returns 0

SELECT max(ISRC) FROM digital_info as m where (ISRC REGEXP "/(\d{5})$/"); // returns NULL
```

please?

---

thanks for those two who answered already - those would be the solutions for above.
But now i realised i need it a bit more complicated:

Not all ISRC's got GBCQV prefix, but i only need MAX from GBCQV prefix?

```
column ISRC
GBCQV0700378
SOME00125963
GBCQV0700382
GBCQV0700387
```

but i still need 00387 returned to me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(ISRC, -5)) FROM digital_info WHERE LEFT(ISRC) = "GBCQV";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i just realised i need more complicated than i just asked. i have edited my original post

Answer (score 2):

Use the string-based [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function:

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(ISRC, 5)) ...
```

Comment: it never occur to me just to use RIGHT()!! need some rest from coding that's for sure... thanks!!