# Extract numeric part of string and get max value in column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table `foo` that stores codes in format `lnnnnn` where `l` is at least one letter and `n` is numeric value. Both letters or numbers can be of various length, so trying to solve this like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329126/mysql-return-max-of-the-last-5-digits-from-column) won't work.

Example:

```
 group | code
 =============
   1   | a0010
   1   | a0012
   1   | a0013
   2   | bn0014
   2   | bn0015
   2   | bn0016
   3   | u0017
   3   | u0018
```

My task is to get current highest numeric value of this column in desired group, to generate new number (like sequence).

Note that I cannot redesign table and explode string and text parts.

So far I tried:

```
select 
    max(code rlike '[0-9]$')
from 
    foo
where
    group = 2
```

but, sadly, `regexp` or `rlike` (synonyms) returns only `0` or `1` (matched or not matched).

Comment: Sadly, mysql's regex implementation doesn't allow you to extract any information from the match, as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507/mysql-use-regex-to-extract-string

Comment: Isn't there any equivalent of `intval()`?

Comment: Yes, there's `cast` (or the implicit conversion shown in the answer below), but that's not the main problem you have. The main problem you have is that you don't know where the letters stop and the digits begin.

Comment: @ex3v The numeric part of the codes are always four digits?

Comment: @ex3v What you're hearing from folks are various ways to determine where the numbers begin (e.g. numbers always start with zero, numbers are always four digits long, etc.). If you know specifics about the number, you can use a simple string operation to extract the numeric portion.

Comment: Come on guys, second sentence of my question: "Both letters or numbers can be of various length".

Answer (score 1):

One method is a brute force method:

```
select grp,
       max(case when substr(code, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' then code + 0
                when substr(code, 2, 1) between '0' and '9' then substr(code, 2) + 0
                when substr(code, 3, 1) between '0' and '9' then substr(code, 3) + 0
                when substr(code, 4, 1) between '0' and '9' then substr(code, 4) + 0
                when substr(code, 5, 1) between '0' and '9' then substr(code, 5) + 0
                when substr(code, 6, 1) between '0' and '9' then substr(code, 6) + 0
                when substr(code, 7, 1) between '0' and '9' then substr(code, 7) + 0
                when substr(code, 8, 1) between '0' and '9' then substr(code, 8) + 0
           end)                
from foo
group by grp;
```

Comment: @ex3v . . . It should be reasonable.  `case` statements and basic string operations are not generally what cause performance issues in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If your numeric codes is always four digits then you can do it like:

```
select groupid, max(right(code,4)) as maxcode
  from foo
 group by groupid
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/775b3/2

Comment: Quoting second sentence from my question: "Both letters or numbers can be of various length"

Answer (score 0):

If all numeric parts start with a `0`:

```
select gp, max(cast(substr(code, instr(code, '0')) as unsigned))
from t
group by gp
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d14e30/3)

If not, for arbitrary numeric parts (that start with any digit):

```
select gp, max(cast(substr(code, instr(code, n)) as unsigned))
from t
join (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
     union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) x
group by gp
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30eb8c/2)

Comment: Quoting second sentence from my question: "Both letters or numbers can be of various length"

Comment: Have tried either query? Neither query assumes any lengths of parts.

Comment: First one doesn't fit. Tried second one and, unfortunately, failed... So far I have two groups, let's say `A` and `G`. Max values for them are `A => a118691`, `B => g21127`. Your query returned: `A => 118691`, `B => 119530`.

Comment: Are you sure there's no row `where code like '%119530'` for B?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Max (for now) `B` group integer value is around 25000